# Making Bootstrap Nav-Pills fixed to the top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, nav-pills

I'm trying to use bootstrap `nav pills` as by navigation bar. I'd like to have the `nav pills` fixed to the top of the page when a user scrolls. I know the `.navbar` class can call the `.navbar-fixed-top` class, which performs this function but is there an equivalent for nav pills?

Comment: I think you should leave some code for us to see so we can have a visual feel of where you are and what exactly you want.